# Set datetime to nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a datetime field in Rails and I want to set it to null on a certain case.

I'm doing

```
@object.update_attributes(assignment_time: nil)
```

and getting the error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there any way to get around this??

Thanks, Uri

Comment: Can you post your full error stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get it done using:

```
@object.update_column(:assignment_time, nil)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is safe?  Seems like some parts of the code assume a non-nil value, and you bypassed this by forcing a nil into the DB.